# Tracking Google DFP Ad Clicks in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, google-dfp

I am wondering if it is possible to track when a user of a website clicks on a Google DFP ad.  I know that the Google DFP website tracks clicks, but I want to be able to track which users (when logged in, using ASP.NET membership) are clicking ads and how many ads.  Is this possible?

Comment: You could add a `click` event handler on the client side targeting the dfp ad (by css class probably) and in this handler you get the info you need and do an ajax call to the server side where you'd handle the information about the user and the ad (s)he clicked. On the server you'd use a webservice or a pagemethod. There might be better ways to do this, that's why this is just a comment.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe That's a good idea, but the problem is that the Google DFP ad is inserted by a script element like this: `<script type="text/javascript">GA_googleFillSlot("adNameGoesHere");</script>`.  If I wrap the script element in another element and add a click handler to that element, will that work?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. You have to do this after the ad is already loaded in your page. *Then*, you'd be able to select the element from the DOM. Can you add the markup rendered on the client containing the ad? Even if the ad is dynamically added through script, you can get the actual markup with Google Chrome.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I don't have Google DFP set up quite yet, so I wasn't able to get the markup.  But from what I could find, it looked like it would be something like `<a href="http://someurl"><img src="http://someurl" /></a>`.  So I'm thinking about wrapping the javascript in a div (with a css class set on it) and using jQuery to select and add a click handler to the ad inside of it.

Comment: Well, it kind of sounds like it might work, but I haven't dealt with DFP myself. Just trying to give suggestions. Hope it works out. Let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been asking a similar question and haven't found an answer yet!

The closest I've come is this - http://support.google.com/richmedia/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=117426

To track clicks using your own click-tracking server, you must include an attribute in the ad tags that specifies the URL for the server. The URL is accessed every time that a user clicks on an ad, enabling your server to count the click. This attribute is click=value, where value is the URL for the clicktracking server. The click-tracking URL should not contain any semicolons (;). If necessary, you can encode semicolons as the equivalent %3B characters.

The sample URL below shows an ad tag with an implemented click attribute:

```
http://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N270.maheshdfasite/B3140338.2;dcopt=1_ist;click=http://site.com/cgi/clicktrack?clickid=12345&page=abcd&goto=;sz=0x0;ord=[timestamp]?
```

so it looks like you could put a URL to your website inside the click handler.

Is this specific to rich media (e.g. flash ads) ?  I don't know!